# Wildcard in the IN clause

Tags: sql

SQL: I want use the wildcard "%" in the IN clause but I'm not getting the results I expect. My query is like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
              FROM INST
WHERE TYPE in ('IP_%_International')
```

Please help resolve this and the solution should be with the IN clause.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do that. IN is for literals, percent signs are for LIKE. Sorry! So `WHERE type LIKE 'IP_%_International'`. But if you have several patterns , the only thing you can do is to OR them together.`WHERE type LIKE 'IP_%_International' OR type LIKE 'some_%_other_pattern'`

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're looking for is not an `IN` Condition, but an `LIKE` Condition. What about searching for

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, FROM INST WHERE TYPE like 'IP_%_International'
```