# Using wildcards with the MYSQL IN Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

`select * from Customers where CustomerID in ('%1%');`

This does not return any results, however

`select * from Customers where CustomerID in ('1');`

Is there any way to use wildcards in the MySQL IN clause, or does it only support raw values?

I have not been able to find anything that confirms or denies this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027351/wildcard-in-the-in-clause

Comment: @danronmoon how did you find this? I searched for 20 minutes and found nothing.

Comment: Try "LIKE" instead of "IN."

Comment: @mysql_lover1982 `mysql "in condition" wildcards`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  You are better off with regular expressions.  Something like this:

```
where customerid regexp 'apple|pear|banana'
```

This will return customer ids that have 'apple' or 'pear' or 'banana' anywhere.

If you really wanted to use `like` you need multiple comparisons:

```
where customerid like '%apple%' or
      customerid like '%pear%' or
      customerid like '%banana%'
```